# How to Use robot_localization package?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am beginner in ROS.

I have a differential drive mobile robot.

I want to use  `robot_localization` package to estimate robot velocity and position from IMU and odometry.

I just download `robot_localization` package, but I can not use it.

```
$   rostopic list

/cmd_vel
/control_vel
/encoder/odom
/imu/data
/md49_data
/md49_encoders
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

My problem is how to make a launch file to use this package to estimate robot velocity and position from IMU and odometry?

and what is its location in the  `~/catkin_ws`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354531/how-to-use-robot_localization-package?/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any parameters and configuration of the robot localization package can be found here

Robot Localization Wiki: (http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html)

On the page (Preparing Your Data for Use with robot_localization) and (Configuring robot_localization) you'll find everything that you need to use the robot_localization package correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-06-10**:
Can you help me to make the launch file?

I can not understand this document [link text](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html)

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-06-10**:
I can't right now, however, in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ5q59H2qaI there is everything that you need. If it is not enough, warn me here and I try to help you. Good luck.